# Comparing to a Null in C++

Tags: c++, null, operators

Ok please have a close inspection on my code below, its just a part of a function

```
void RepeatWord(){
    system("cls");
    string word = NULL;
    string newword = NULL;
    int repeats = 0;
    while(true){
        if(word == NULL){
            cout<<"Currently no word is stored..";
            cout<<"\n\nPlease enter a word: ";
            cin>>word;
        }
....
```

well I been working with other programming languages and I am always doing a comparison with a `NULL` value but in C++... it seems to be a different situation. The error says..

> error: no match for 'operator==' in 'word == 0'

well I was wondering I am just comparing to a `NULL` and I really don't know why this is wrong. Is comparing a value to a `NULL` to C++ is different? please teach me. Thanks

Note: I know more ruby than java

Comment: Don't set `std::string`s to null (an exception would be thrown had this run). `std::string word;` is an empty string.

Comment: Woah woah... you can't null objects like that. This isn't Java.

Comment: @chris so its really impossible to set `NULL` values in C++?

Comment: @Mahan You can set *pointers* to `NULL`. But not *objects*.

Comment: @Mahan, Set pointers to `NULL` (or better, `nullptr`). Types aren't nullable by default. If you want that, use a pointer or `boost::optional`.

Comment: @Mysticial I told you before I worked already in other languages.. so surprised `NULL` doesn't work here :((

Comment: @Mahan Yeah, C and C++ are different in this respect. I suggest you read up on C++ objects first. Pointers can come later. (and you arguably don't need them much in modern C++)

Comment: Something that might help you: In some other languages you are probably familiar with, when you declare a variable, you are actually declaring a reference that might refer to a valid object, or it might refer to nothing (a null reference), and it can be moved from object to object.  In C++, when you declare a variable, you are creating an object.  The name you use is that object's name, so it can't refer to another object, and it can't refer to nothing.  That's what pointers are for, though pointers themselves are actually objects too, and they refer to objects by storing their address.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to compare a object with `NULL`, You cannot compare objects with a `NULL`. You need to compare a pointer. In doing so you check if the pointer is pointing to something that is not a valid object.

In your case you want to check if `std::string` is empty. You can use member functions provided by `std::string`, `std::string::empty()`.

Considering Your questions, I am stressing the need for a good learning book:

[The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: a pointer? can you point me to a tutorial where I can learn how to use pointers? so I can set `NULL` values?

Comment: @Mahan the point of c++ with stl is that you don't need pointers.

Comment: @Mahan: Please pick up a good book from the link marked inline to answer

Comment: oh yeah this works for now.. thanks, empty string not null string

Comment: @Mahan, it's incredible, beginners love pointers, pointers are where all the mistakes happen, so beginners write lousy code. Ben's point is right on the money, you don't need pointers *most* of the time. And because in a language without garbage collection they are very tricky you should avoid them, at least until you get a bit more experience.

Answer (score 3):

If you are coming from the Java world, you will indeed discover that object in C++ are not handled the same way. In C++, unless explicitely stated, data are manipulated directly. In Java, object are completely managed by the VM, and because of this, it makes sense to let programs access them by reference only. Hence, whenever you write a Java program, you must tell the VM to allocate an object using `new`, and until then assign `null` to variable of class instances. Following the same principle, if you assign an object variable to another, both will *refer* the same object, and calling a method on either will call that method on the same underlying instance.

In C++, there are 2 different mechanisms to obtain the same result:

- using pointers, whose syntax for the type `T` is

  ```
  T *t;
  ```

  so that `std::string *word;` will define a variable named `word` holding a pointer to `std::string`.
- using a reference:

  ```
  T &t;
  ```

In C++, both of these are actually types, ie. `std::string`, `std::string *`, `std::string &` are three different types.  The first one is really denoting the structured value itself, while the two other denotes an indirection to a value of the type `std::string`.

The difference between these types indirections are explained by this SO [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c).

In your code, you will have to either replace all occurences of `NULL` by the empty string literal `""`, or use pointers and allocate the instances using a `new` statement before trying to use the object - like in the line `cin >> word;`.